# Ignore test to be executed locally in spring boot

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I need to disable execution of one unit test on local environment. We run unit tests in local with `local-test` profile

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local-test
```

I need to execute my test at all profiles **except** `local-test` How can I achieve this?

Here is my test, if I put `value = "!local-test"` it does not work

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "local-test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EnvironmentTests {

    @Test
    public void TestNightTimeFormatCorrect() {
        throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, hope it will be useful for somebody.

In this case `TestNightTimeFormatCorrect` will be executed every time when there is no `local-test` profile. It will be alse executed when no profile is set.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@ProfileValueSourceConfiguration(EnvironmentTests.ProfileProfileValueSource.class)
@IfProfileValue(name = "local-test", value = "false")
public class EnvironmentTests {

    @Test
    public void TestNightTimeFormatCorrect() {
        throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
    }


    public static class ProfileProfileValueSource implements ProfileValueSource
    {
        @Override
        public String get(String string)
        {
            final String systemProfiles = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", System.getProperty("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", ""));
            final String[] profiles = systemProfiles.split(",");
            return Arrays.asList(profiles).contains(string) ? "true" : "false";
        }

    }
}
```